# How to find if related rows include a specific value

Tags: dax

I have a one to many relationship. I want a meassure that checks a column in the "many" table to see if a value exists for the row on the "one" side.

Table "One"

- a
- b
- c

Table "Many"

- a : 1
- a : 2
- a : 3
- a : 4
- a : 5
- a : 6
- b : 1
- b : 2

I want a query that finds if 5 exists against each value in the "one" table.

It sounds like CONTAINS can do this, however it seems to be asking for defined values for both tables, whereas I want to calculate it for all values on the "One" side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tables defined in M:

```
//One
let
    Source = #table({"Letter"}, {{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}})
in
    Source
```

```
//Many
let
    Source = #table({"Letter", "Number"}, {{"a", 1}, {"a", 2}, {"a", 3}, {"a", 4}, {"a", 5}, {"a", 6}, {"b", 1}, {"b", 2}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Number", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

And then we load these to the model. It will likely auto-detect a relationship between these two tables on the field, Letter. If it doesn't, then create this relationship:

[image: relationships in model]

Here's a calculated column using `CONTAINS`

```
ManyHasFive with CONTAINS = 
CONTAINS (
  'Many',          // Check columns in this table for following criteria
  'Many'[Letter],  // Check all values in this column...
  'One'[Letter],   // ..for this value - here, this is 'One'[Letter] in row context
                   // i.e. the current row's value
  'Many'[Number],  // Additionally, check the values in this column...
  5                // ..for this value
)
```

Here's a version that leverages the relationship:

```
ManyHasFive with relationship = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Many' ),
    'Many'[Number] = 5
) > 0
```

Or, with the relationship defined, you can just add the appropriate columns to a visual and filter that.

Table visual with:
- 'One'[Letter]
- 'Many'[Number] (set summarization to "Do Not Summarize")

Visual level filter for 'Many'[Number] = 5

[image: here's the visual!]